# Handle json response (from PHP and mysql) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

Facing trouble in hadling the Json response from php. I am using AngularJs to display the recieved Json data. I am new to angular and tried a simple exercise for starters. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html ng-app="app">
<head>
   <title>PHP MySQL API Consumed with AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body>
     <div ng-controller="GetUsers">

    <table border="1">
       <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr></thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="user in users"><td>{{user.user_id}}</td><td>  {{user.first_name }}</td><td>{{user.user_city}}</td></tr>
       </tbody>
       </tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
 <script>

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('GetUsers', function ($scope,$http){
        $http.get('http://localhost/angmysql/api.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        });
      }
   });

  </script>

<script src="angular.js"></script>

<body>
</html>
```

*api.php*

```
<?php

    $db_name  = 'dbtuts';
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbtuts') or die('Error connecting to database');

    $sql = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM users");

    $emparray = array();

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($emparray);

    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: What is the trouble ? What contains the data variable in your success function on the http promise ?

Comment: you can make this like `$http.get('http://localhost/angmysql/api.php').then(function (response){ console.log(response)})` to see you response how looks like and your `users` in `response.data`

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed into the callback by $http is a object, where the response body is stored in the .data field.

Try this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/angmysql/api.php').success(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
});
```

From [AngularDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
The response object has these properties:

data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

Comment: In that case I think the returned result is not what you think. Try to log it to console. `console.log(response.data)` what do you get? Need more information, otherwise this is just be guessing.